# Which rolling release distribution?

Tags: linux-distributions

i would like to suggest me a good rolling release distribution. I use ubuntu, but I would like a distribution that allows me to tinker more with stuff and learn more about linux instead of offering an out-of-the-box OS

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

[ArchLinux](http://www.archlinux.org/) pretty much covers all that. Tinkering is not only allowed, but encouraged :-)